# UITextField - Multiple Lines

Tags: text, uitextfield, field, lines, cgrect

I'm trying to add lines to my UITextField (my code is below), however, when the typer gets to the end of the text field, instead of going to the next line it keeps going on the same line forever! How do I get it to go to the next line? Thanks.

```
fldNotes = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(labelLeft,controlTop+5,320 - (2 * labelLeft),200)];
fldNotes.text = te.notes;
fldNotes.placeholder = [theApp.adb GetHC:@"NotesName"];
fldNotes.clearButtonMode = UITextFieldViewModeWhileEditing;
fldNotes.tag = 100;
fldNotes.borderStyle = UITextBorderStyleRoundedRect;
[fldNotes setReturnKeyType:UIReturnKeyDone];
[fldNotes setEnablesReturnKeyAutomatically:YES];
fldNotes.delegate = self;

[contentView addSubview:fldNotes];
```

Answer (score 1):

use a `UITextView` instead. This allows for multi-line text.

Comment: Bear in mind that UITextView does not have all the features of UITextField, such as placeholder text, and that dismissing the keyboard with the return key is difficult/bad practice, for example.

Answer (score 1):

You can also customize your UITextView to look alike UITextField by using this.

```
 myTextView.layer.cornerRadius = 5;
    [myTextView.layer setBorderColor:[[[UIColor grayColor] colorWithAlphaComponent:0.5] CGColor]];
    [myTextView.layer setBorderWidth:2.0];    
    myTextView.clipsToBounds = YES;
```

Dont forget to `import <QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` and you wil get rid of the error.

Hope this helps Someone:)

Comment: Won't the style you're trying to mimmic vary with the IOS version?